# Parameterized logging in a Webapp with garbage-free Log4j

Tags: java, logging, memory-leaks, log4j, log4j2

Facts gathered:

1. log4j 2.6 provides garbage-free logging, where instead of creating new strings everytime, it reuses the stringbuilder saved in the threadlocal.
2. Garbage free mode of log4j is by default disabled in webApps, as webApps reuse threads, and saving logs in the threads can cause building up of the stringBuilder over days.

I am using log4j in a WebApp, and verified that `ENABLE_THREADLOCALS` field is false.

When i log in the following ways:

1. `log.info("log statement with parameter {}", someString);`
2. `log.info(""log statement with concatenation " + someString");`

I see, the first statement remains in the heap-memory even after full GC.
Where as the second statement does not.

I went through the code for log.info, and found, that the first one uses "`ParameterizedMessage`", while the second one uses "`SimpleMessage`".

`ParametrizedMessage` creation is done using `ThreadLocal`s , even for WebApp, and it has a comment :

```
 "// storing JDK classes in ThreadLocals does not cause memory leaks in web apps, so this is okay"
```

My question is, is the above comment true, because I am facing memory leak issues when I log using {} in a webApp.

PS: There are no issues when the webApp is restarted. Everything is cleared out on restart. But it is a concern when the webApp is running continuously for days, and the threadLocals keep on increasing in size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you hit a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1417

> The org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Unbox class stores a non-JDK class
>   (Unbox$State) in a static ThreadLocal field.
>
> This may cause memory leaks in containers which share thread pools
>   between applications.

try using version 2.6.2 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am already using 2.6.2. Also, in my case StringBuilders are being stored directly in the threadLocals, without any Unbox class. So, the above does not fit in my case.